# $http jsonp response in error callback

Tags: angularjs

I am working with jsonp using Angular $http service.

The server require basic auth, so I setup in the app startup,

```
 angular.module('app')
        .run(['$route', 'base64', '$http', function ($route, base64, $http) {

            //hook up the routing
            var encoded = base64.encode("username" + ':' + "password");
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded;
        }]);
```

And here is a jsonp call that I am trying to make

```
  function getFilms(company){
    $http.jsonp(config.serviceUrl + 'moment/films', {
                params: {
                    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                    project: company
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }).error(function (data,status) {

                console.log(status);
            });
      }
```

The problem is, the response comes back in error callback instead of success callback. Everything has been setup on the backend properly and even I checked out the log on the server, nothing seems to be wrong. Not sure why it's not return response in success callback. Any suggestion please?

Comment: you're going to need to povide a lot more information

Comment: What is the value of `config.serviceUrl`? What is the HTTP status code returned by the server?

Comment: config.serviceUrl is the base address for the 3rd party server. Where as if I see the network tab, the response is 200 OK but the promise I return with $http.jsonp takes me to the error callback instead of success callback. Please let me know if any more information you need

Comment: What is the HTTP status inside of the error callback? It should be available as the second parameter if you use `.error` to register the callback, or in `response.status` if you `.then` or `.catch`.

Comment: it says 404, any idea quite weired.

Comment: Well here you go :). Can't help you much more because we cannot reproduce the problem. However it might help if you provided code that make a little more sense. In the current code, there is no observable relation between the top part and the bottom part. There is also no indication of what `datacontext` or `fileName` are. Please provide a minimal but complete piece of code that we can make sense of. We should be able to trace the execution flow from the `$http.jsonp` call up to the callbacks.

Comment: I hope the updated code make sense

Comment: Please let me know if anything else you need to know.

Comment: I don't know how to help you further. Are you really sure that the network tab shows a 200 OK response? What is its payload like? Is the URL of the request show the `callback` and `project` params? Investigate everything about that request.

Comment: Yes, please see each and everything what's going on with request. https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9f0fy1n5r877bd/request.PNG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59541/discussion-between-user3398887-and-hugo-wood).